# Weird problem with android theming

Tags: android

I am a newbie when compared to android development and i am just going through the sample projects to get a hang of it. I just tried to copy a style from Wikitionary( a sample app that comes with android SDK).

```
<style name="LookupTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light">
   <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/lookup_bg</item>
 </style>
```

And specified this as the default theme in manifest file. This produced an effect, like this.[image]

This is exactly what i wanted.. Now i have added a preference page to allow user to choose from a list of themes to be applied. Hence, i removed the theme attribute from manifest file(to use default theme) and i tried to apply theme programatically. Like this

```
SharedPreferences sPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(act.getApplicationContext());
    String themeid = sPref.getString("theme_pref", "1");
    int themeID = Integer.valueOf(themeid);
    if(themeID== 2){
        Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, "Light theme have been choosen");
        act.setTheme(R.style.LookupTheme);
    }
```

Now the same theme gets applied programatically(as opposed to a declarative approach) and produces an effect like this.
[image]

Can someone explain what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at this:

[Applying a Theme to your Application](http://www.anddev.org/applying_a_theme_to_your_application-t817.html)